# plotting multiple google maps to page

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I'm trying to append more than one Google Map to a page. But it seems like I'm having some trouble.

This would be the template I'm using to ( with Handlebars.js ) to create the same block more than once, about 50 times :

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars-template">
{{#each productListing}}
    <div class="product-listing-wrapper">
        <div class="product-listing">
            <div class="left-side-content">
                <div class="thumb-wrapper" data-image-link="{{ThumbnailUrl}}">
                    <i class="thumb">
                        <img src="{{ThumbnailUrl}}" alt="Thumb">
                        <span class="zoom-image"></span>
                    </i>
                </div>
                <div class="google-maps-wrapper">
                    <div class="google-coordonates-wrapper">
                        <div class="google-coordonates">
                            <p>{{LatLon.Lat}}</p>
                            <p>{{LatLon.Lon}}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="google-maps-button">
                        <a class="google-maps" href="#">Google Maps</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="right-side-content">
                <div class="map-canvas-wrapper">
                    <div id="map-canvas" class="map-canvas" data-latitude="{{LatLon.Lat}}" data-longitude="{{LatLon.Lon}}"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="content-wrapper"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{{/each}}
```

And I'm trying to append the map to the `#map-canvas` id. With the following block of code I'm doing the plotting :

```
Cluster.prototype.initiate_map_assembling = function() {
    return $(this.map_canvas_wrapper_class).each(function(index, element) {
        var canvas = $(element).children();
        var latitude = $(canvas).attr('data-latitude');
        var longitude = $(canvas).attr('data-longitude');

        var coordinates = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);

        var options = {
            zoom: 9,
            center: coordinates,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map($(canvas), options);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: coordinates,
            map: map
        });
    });     
};
```

This way I'm "looping" through all the parent classes of the id I'm trying to append the map to, but the map would only append to the first id. I tried to append it to all of the id's in other ways but with the same results.

So what would you suggest me to do to make it work as I would expect it, append the map to each of the id's ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using a lib like jQuery then change

```
var map = new google.maps.Map($(canvas), options);
```

to

```
var map = new google.maps.Map($(canvas)[0], options);
```

That might work, otherwise a link to your demo would be helpful.

Comment: This did it :) I tried it, but without the `[0]`, I tried `[index]`

Answer (score 1):

In HTML you can't use the same `ID` for multiple nodes.  (Actually you can, but you cannot select those after the first one.)  So an easy solution comes: just omit the `id` of the canvas `div`, or append `index` after it.

Comment: I thought so too :| So the only thing would be to have something else after that id name ..

Comment: @Roland - but why can't you use the class name you already have?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, loop through the classes instead of ids ?

Comment: So, how would I apply the map ?